# Transform a python dataframe into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to transform a pandas dataframe into a dictionary, I'm currently getting this output:

```
{'country': {0: 'BRAZIL', 1: 'BRAZIL'}, 'store_nick': {0: 'store_a', 1: 'store_b'}, 'store': {0: 'STORE_A', 1: 'STORE_B'}}
```

But I want this format:

```
{{'store_a','BRAZIL', 'STORE_A'}, {'store_b','BRAZIL', 'STORE_B'}}
```

This is my code:

```
dimensions[['fieldA','fieldB','fieldC']].to_dict()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `{{'store_a','BRAZIL', 'STORE_A'}, {'store_b','BRAZIL', 'STORE_B'}}` is not a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is not a dictionary. If you want to store collections in a `set`, you'll need to store them in `tuple`s, since they are hashable.

```
>>> set(df.apply(tuple, 1).values)
{('BRAZIL', 'STORE_A', 'store_a'), ('BRAZIL', 'STORE_B', 'store_b')}
```

Alternatively, if a list of lists works, then `tolist` is the way to go.

```
>>> df.values.tolist()
[['BRAZIL', 'STORE_A', 'store_a'], ['BRAZIL', 'STORE_B', 'store_b']]
```